# SSRS action go to URL open file in new window - backslash

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink

I tried using this to open new window in SSRS go to URL action. but it replaces backslash to %5C

Instead of this:

```
javascript:void(window.open('\\ServerName\THUMBNAILS\Filename.JPG'))
```

I get this:

```
javascript:void(window.open('%5C%5CServerName%5CTHUMBNAILS%5CFilename.JPG'))
```

Thus clicking the link does not bring me to the JPG file. it just redirect to SSRS report manager

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this by using file:///// (yes there is five slashes)

> ="javascript:void(window.open('file://///ServerName/THUMBNAILS/Filename.JPG','_blank'))"

seems to like forward slash but not back slash

Comment: This does not work if you are using latest version of Chrome or Edge Dev (Chromium)